# R - How to vectorize the calculation in a 2d matrix?

Tags: r

I would like to create a matrix of n x n dimension, with the values

```
f = matrix(0,n,n)
for (x in (1:n)) {
    for (y in (1:n)) {
        f[x,y] = x^2 + y^2
    }
}
```

Is there a way to vectorize this (to avoid the two loops) to speed the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `outer`

```
outer(x, y, function(x, y) x^2 + y^2)
```

For example

```
x <- 1:4
y <- 2:5
outer(x, y, function(x, y) x^2 + y^2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   10   17   26
[2,]    8   13   20   29
[3,]   13   18   25   34
[4,]   20   25   32   41
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
n <- 10
M <- matrix(rep(1:n,n), ncol=n, byrow=T)
f <- (M**2)+t((M**2))
f
```